# Custom ViewModel not displaying values in TextBoxFor TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Object1.Name)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a custom Model, which contains another custom object (Objects1.Object2), I am correctly populating the object prior to display in the view and

<%: Model.Object1.Name %> displays the data correctly yet 
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Object1.Name) %> displays no data.

I am new to MVC and would love to get around this issue as it is a stopping point to creating custom data model.

Any info is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to modify this in a POST action? If you are then note that HTML helpers such as `TextBoxFor` will first read data from model state and after this from the model. So if your post action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SomeViewModel model)
{
    model.Object1.Name = "some new value";
    return View(model);
}
```

you need to remove it from model state or you will always get old value:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SomeViewModel model)
{
    ModelState.Remove("Object1.Name");
    model.Object1.Name = "some new value";
    return View(model);
}
```

If you are doing this in the GET action there shouldn't be absolutely any problems displaying the value:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new SomeViewModel
    {
        Object1 = new TypeOfObject1
        {
            Name = "foo bar"
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and then in the view:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Object1.Name) %>
```

should display the proper value.

Comment: This is a simple get, the only item I am doing somewhat differently is I have a parent view with two nested views (RenderPartial("view",Model) yet still not data in the TextBoxFor yet I have the same data in a <%: Model.Object.Value %>.  Not sure if the nested views are causing the issue.  thanks again

Comment: Darin, you were correct (removing items from ModelState).  Adding ModelState.Clear(); corrected the problem.  I was wondering if you could give me insight/links to explain this as I was under the impression, adding a new object to View(newobject) would clear the original state.  thanks!

Comment: @user701236, ModelState could be automatically populated by GET/POST request parameters, so if you try to modify a value of the model that's already present in this dictionary HTML helpers will still use the old value and that's by design.