# Select dropdown item in controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Good day

On my view I have a dropdownlist like so:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Colour, new { @class = "col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Colour, new SelectList(Model.VehicleColour, "Value", "Text", Model.Colour), new { id = "Colour", @class = "btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**Updated.**  In a certain condition I need to set the selected item in my controller. currently I am trying to achieve this by doing it like so (but this is not working):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult VehicleDetails(VehicleDisplay model)
{
    // This section depends on the condition and it gets the item id that I need
    // to select in the dropdown 
    if (Session["ColourID"] != null)
    {
        model.Colour = long.Parse(Session["ColourID"].ToString());
    }
    #endIf

    model.VehicleColour = GetVehicleColour();
    foreach (SelectListItem colour in model.VehicleColour)
    {
        if (colour.Value == model.Colour.ToString())
        {
            colour.Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            colour.Selected = false;
        }
    }
    return PartialView("VehicleDetails", model);
}
```

**GetVehicleColour()**

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetVehicleColour()
{
    var colours = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var colour = new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = "0",
        Text = "Please select a Vehicle Colour",
        Selected = true
    };

    /* Get Colour values fron database */

    foreach (ColorObject method in dbList)
    {
        colour = new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = method.Id.ToString(),
            Text = method.Description,
            Selected = false
        };
        colours.Add(colour);
    }
    return colours;
}
```

**VehicleModel**

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Colour ")]
[Range(1, long.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please select a Vehicle Colour")]
public long? Colour { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> VehicleColour { get; set; }
```

can you please assist me with this issue?

Comment: There is no point setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` when binding to a model property (its ignored by the `DropDownListFor()` method which internally generates a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`). Its the value of `Colour` which determines what is selected - if it matches one of the option vales, then that option will be selected.

Comment: And do not add a `Please select a Vehicle Colour` option in the `SelectList` - use one of the overloads that accepts a `labelOption` and there is no point generating a 2nd identical `SelectList` from the first one. The view should be just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Colour, Model.VehicleColour, "Please select a Vehicle Colour", new { @class = "btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" })`

Comment: I have removed the `Selected` property but it still does not select the selected value

Comment: Then that means the value your setting does not match one of the `method.Id` values you using to generate the options.

Comment: The `model.Colour` matches a `method.id`

Comment: Then that option WILL be selected. And if its not - then its dues to something else you have not shown us.

Comment: but that option does not get selected

Comment: Then its due to something else. Look at the html your generating and take note of say the `value` attribute of the 3rd option. Then hard code that same value - i.e. `model.Colour = ??` and you will see that it does select the 3rd option.

Comment: I had a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614615/custom-viewmodel-not-displaying-values-in-textboxfor-textboxformodel-model-o) and it solved my issue

Comment: Then I suggest you delete the question - this is of no use to anyone since it does not even include the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this;

In controller you should write;

```
List<VehicleColour> lstColour = null;
lstColour = GetVehicleColour();
ViewBag.lstColour = new SelectList(lstColour , "Colour", "Colour", selected Colour);
```

And your view should be like below;

```
 @Html.DropDownList("lstColour", null, new { id = "Colour", @class = "btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" })
```

Comment: @StephenMuecke this is working fine. I used this in many my projects. So plz don't judge anyone's code without confirmation. And obviously who voted up also get solution that's why he/she voted.

Comment: If you have answer then write here. Don't comment on anyone's answer.

Comment: It wont even compile, let alone work! And it has nothing to do with the question. Ad suggest to use `DropDownList()` instead of the strongly typed `DropDownListFor()` method as OP is doing is terrible.